# Notifiying new comments on fanPage wall

Tags: facebook, comments, notify

I've been trying for 3 days and still no way to publish notification about new comments on my fanPage. I created a comment application and it is getting the comments, but I want to notify the fanPage admins about new comments. I tried to use:

**$facebook->api_client->feed_publishTemplatizedAction($feed_title_template, $feed_title_data, $feed_body_template, "", "", $page_id, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, $page_id);**

but I'm having problems with this $facebok variable, it's not accepting my app id and secret key. Aready read all the documentation and still no sollution. **Don't want to notify the users**, just the fanPage. Any ideas?

Comment: also tried FB.Event.subscribe('comment.create'), but only worked for opening message boxes

Comment: That event, 'comment.create', is only used for the comments plugin and is capture only on the HTML page where the comments plugin is being commented into.  There is no remote way to get notifications from the comment plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to implement RealTime updates.

> you can subscribe to the page's feed in the same way you subscribe to
>   a user's feed - the subscription topic should be user and the
>   subscription field should be feed

See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/realtime/